# Deactivating editing toolbar for multiple features

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, editing, features

I am creating a toolbar for a number of features as follows:

```
 for (var graphicNum = 0; graphicNum < graphicList.length; graphicNum++) {
        if (graphicList[graphicNum].symbol != undefined) {
            //Initializing the toolbar to be used for the feature modification process
            moveToolbarLabel = new esri.toolbars.Edit(app.map);
            moveToolbarLabel.activate(esri.toolbars.Edit.MOVE | esri.toolbars.Edit.SCALE | esri.toolbars.Edit.ROTATE, graphicList[graphicNum]);
        }
    }
```

The features all get the scale and rotation points around them as expected. However when I click a button to remove these scale and rotation points by deactivating the toolbar as follows:

```
if (moveToolbarLabel != undefined) {
        moveToolbarLabel.deactivate();
    }
```

the scaling and rotation points do no go. Is there any additional code that has to be included since there would be multiple toolbar due to having the toolbar activated for multiple features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first `for` loop, you are creating many instances of the edit toolbar. As you're creating these, save references to them to an array. Something like this:

```
var allToolbars = []; // <- added
 for (var graphicNum = 0; graphicNum < graphicList.length; graphicNum++) {
        if (graphicList[graphicNum].symbol != undefined) {
            //Initializing the toolbar to be used for the feature modification process
            moveToolbarLabel = new esri.toolbars.Edit(app.map);
            moveToolbarLabel.activate(esri.toolbars.Edit.MOVE | esri.toolbars.Edit.SCALE | esri.toolbars.Edit.ROTATE, graphicList[graphicNum]);
            allToolbars.push(moveToolbarLabel); // <- added
        }
    }
```

Then when you're deactivating, loop through the `allToolbars` array and call `deactivate()` on each of the elements in that array.